# NASM - suppress segment base warnings for 64 bit code

Tags: nasm

I'm talking about this things:

> warning: ds segment base generated, but will be ignored in 64-bit mode

I know that -w option can be used to suppress warnings in NASM, but from the list of warnings showed by the help menu nothing fits this type of warning. And -w-all gets rid of everything, except this.

Any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Since that particular error doesn't seem to be one of the [suppressible ones](http://nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.09rc1/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.24) (as you've stated, I'd just use `sed` as a post-processing step, piping the output through something like:

```
sed '/^warning: .. segment base generated, but will be ignored in 64-bit mode$/d'
```

Even if you're using `nasm` on Windows, you can still get the [GNUWin32 port of `sed`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) to do the job.

---

> And before you complain about this being a kludge, you should know that some of my greatest achievements were kludges, and many of them have out-lived my more well-designed code.
>
> :-)